# Unit testing void methods w/ dependencies that change state with subsequent operation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

I am having trouble unit testing a void method and mocking a dependency when that dependency changes the state of the passed reference.  I understand that side-effects can be observed on a void method and behavior can also be observed but I am having difficulty applying those guidelines to this code.  There are similar questions out there but I couldn't find anything dealing w/ subsequent local changes to state.  I am using JUnit and Mockito... Here's a contrived version of the code I am talking about:

```
@Mock
MergingObject mergingObject;

@Override
public void process(Foo foo1) {
    Foo foo2 = getAnInstanceOfFoo(); // private
    Foo foo3 = mergingObject.merge(foo1, foo2); // public
    foo1.copySomeValues(foo3);
}
```

The conundrum here is if I create a mock for the MergingObject object.  The state change I expect disappears when we mock the object because the merge(...) operation never gets called.  I can try to just verify that merge(...) was called with the correct instances of foo1 and foo2 but the subsequent copySomeValues(...) call still throws a NullPointerException.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you could implement merge on your mock object! Not exacly clear though, you aren't saying Merge changes foo1 and or foo2 are you?

Comment: That's pretty interesting if I can do that.  Merge in this case returns a new instance based upon the contents of foo1 and foo2.  This necessitates the subsequent "copy" step.

Comment: Thought you were testing for a side effect for a minute. I have a KISS attitude to solving that issue, get rid of side effect.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstand you, you are setting up the mergingObject as a mock, but you aren't setting up the behaviour of the mock. You need to tell the mocked mergingObject that when .merge is called, return something. That something can be anything you like, and you can verify that the returned object from process() is the same object.

you can set up the behaviour with the stubbing syntax in mockito. I've never used mockito but looking at the site it's something like this

```
when(mergingObject.merge(something, somethingelse).return(new Foo());
```

you'll need to be careful with how you specify the arguments forsomething and something else so they match your foo1 and foo2

Comment: I see what you mean.  Now returning a different instance of Foo from the merge(...) will of course remove the changes from the getAnInstanceOfFoo(...) call.  So it sounds like I need a verification step to make sure that the invocation to merge(...) was with the expected object and I also need an assertion on the copyValues(...) method (now using my mocked return object) to see if that method changes state correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I noticed from what you've posted is it's far from clear what you are testing and why.

Given Merge has been delegated to another class which will have it's own set of tests.
I would have created a foo1 and a foo3 to test CopySomeValues. Merge wouldn't feature at all.